# retrieving data from a nested hash object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I create a form like this

```
    @question = Question.new 
    3.times {@question.answers.build}
```

If it doesn't validate, I'm redisplaying the form with the data populated. It's not hard to populate the question data

```
  @question = @user.questions.new(session[:question])
```

However, I'm having trouble getting the nested values from the session hash for the answer model (which has a content and link field). This is not working.

```
 3.times {@question.answers.build(:content => session[:question][:answers_attributes][:content], :correctanswer => session[:question][:answers_attributes][:correctanswer]) }
```

I think it's because of the 0, 1 and 2 iteration in the hash object. For example, this is a snippet from the hash object (shown in full below)

```
"answers_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"content"=>"",
```

But I don't know how I would represent that when building the question answers

```
 3.times {@question.answers.build(:content => session[:question][:answers_attributes][:content]....
```

When I'm trying to build I'm not representing the iteration while trying to extract the data from the hash object. Can you explain how I would modify this line to pass the parameters to `question.answers.build`

This is the hash object.

```
>    Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "question"=>{"content"=>"Lick me",
> "link"=>"bab", "answers_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"content"=>"",
> "correctanswer"=>"0", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "1"=>{"content"=>"",
> "correctanswer"=>"1", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "2"=>{"content"=>"",
> "correctanswer"=>"0", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, "commit"=>"Create
> Question"}
```

Comment: I want to store data in same format, may you send the code of  model and form please.

Comment: it's all in this railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are three sets of key/values in the parameters, it's better to loop through the parameters and build the questions.answers on each iteration through, like this. This way you can represent the iteration in the nested hash by passing in the key.

```
@question = @user.questions.new(session[:question])
session[:question][:answers_attributes].each do |k,v|
        @question.answers.build(:content => session[:question][:answers_attributes][k][:content], :correctanswer => session[:question][:answers_attributes][k][:correctanswer])

       end
```